# something wrong with valueOf function

Tags: java, android

If statement works fine. It's code is shown below

```
if (getInput1.getText() != null) {
   float answer2 = Float.valueOf(getInput2.getText().toString());
   float answer3 = Float.valueOf(getInput3.getText().toString());
   float answer= answer2/answer3;
   textOut1.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
}
```

but then I add second if statement (code below)

```
EditText getInput1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput1);
EditText getInput2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput2);
EditText getInput3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput3);                

if (getInput1.getText() != null) {
   float  answer2 = Float.valueOf(getInput2.getText().toString());
   float answer3 = Float.valueOf(getInput3.getText().toString());
   float answer= answer2/answer3;
   textOut1.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
}                   

if (getInput2.getText()!= null ){       
   float answer1 = Float.valueOf(getInput1.getText().toString());
   float answer3 = Float.valueOf(getInput3.getText().toString());
   float answer= answer1*answer3;
   textOut1.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
}
```

logCat says that something goes wrong with `valueOf` function. Where could be a mistake?

logcat shows:

```
08-18 17:10:28.918: INFO/ActivityManager(569): Displayed activity com.easyPhys.start/.mechanics: 261 ms
08-18 17:10:29.648: INFO/ActivityManager(569): Starting activity: Intent { action=com.easyPhys.start.velocity comp={com.easyPhys.start/com.easyPhys.start.velocity} }
08-18 17:10:30.008: INFO/ActivityManager(569): Displayed activity com.easyPhys.start/.velocity: 366 ms
08-18 17:10:47.308: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(755): No keyboard for id 0
08-18 17:10:47.308: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(755): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-18 17:10:48.338: DEBUG/dalvikvm(704): GC freed 971 objects / 73712 bytes in 126ms
08-18 17:10:51.348: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(755): Shutting down VM
08-18 17:10:51.348: WARN/dalvikvm(755): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
08-18 17:10:51.348: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:296)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:327)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at com.easyPhys.start.velocity$1.onClick(velocity.java:86)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2179)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:3828)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6291)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3368)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1707)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1197)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1993)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1525)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
08-18 17:10:51.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: print the strings sent to `Float.valueOf` before the function call to see their value

Comment: Please make *some* effort to format your code to make it easily readable.

Comment: I included logcat and my program force closes down

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: float answer1 = Float.valueOf(getInput1.getText().toString());
gives that error. For me it looks that I need to define something. Something is conflicting but I can't see a mistake. I was working with c++ and this looks to be fine but I am wrong.

Comment: these two if statements works just fine then they awre separate (one of them is commented out) but not then they are together

Comment: Please help me, I stuck on this for ages

Comment: I tried to add three different buttons for every if statement but it still doesn't work so I think I am doing something wrong what I can't in createOn () function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If something is wrong with the Float.ValueOf method you should get a [NumberFormatException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29). So the value you put in ValueOf() could not be converted to a float

Comment: This. That error is caused by something that's not kosher in your `valueOf()` statement. Have the `Log.i()` print out the values before interpreting them and see what's wrong.